# How to check if a Pid is member of a list of Pids in Erlang?

Tags: erlang, erlang-shell

I have a function that sets a value to a process Pid and I can have a process depend on another one. So if I set a value to a process then I have to also set the value to the processes that depend on it. However, if there is a circle between the processes

```
i.e. A depends on B and B depends on A
```

then I want to return an error message.

I try to do this by passing a list of Pids which have already changed values so that if I come across the same Pid twice (By checking if it is a member of the list of Pids) then the whole function stops. This is my code:

```
set_values(Pid, Value, PidSet, PidList) ->
  case lists:member(Pid, PidList) of 
    false -> io:format("Setting Value~n"),
    lists:map(fun(Pid) ->
     Pid ! {self(), set_value, Value, [Pid | PidList]} end, PidSet);
    true -> io:format("circle_detected~n"),
    Pid ! {circle_detected}
  end.
```

When I run it, I get this error:

```
=ERROR REPORT==== 2-Nov-2014::17:47:45 ===
Error in process <0.888.0> with exit value: {badarg,[{lists,member,
[<0.888.0>,empty_list],[]},{process,set_viewer_values,4,[{file,"process.erl"},{line,56}]},
{process,looper,2,[{file,"process.erl"},{line,116}]}]}
```

From what I understand I give bad arguments to lists:member function.
What should I do?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read your error message, you have `{lists,member,
[<0.888.0>,empty_list] ...`, where `lists` is module, `member` is function name, and `[<0.888.0>,empty_list]` are aruguments (two) presented as list.  So you are making call to `lists:nenber/2` with `PidList` variable being **atom** `empty_list`.  And this gives you an error.

So you need to look into how you funciton is being called (prefered),  or create some pattern match on `PidList` like

```
set_values(Pid, Value, PidSet, _PidList = empty_list) ->
   ...
```

Comment: thanks turns out i was calling `empty_list` after all :)

Comment: It happens :) Remember that you can pattern match on `[]`, so there is no need for `empty_list` abstraction.  And you could try using [dialyzer](http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/dialyzer/dialyzer_chapter.html) which would probably warn you about such type-error.